# How to save RGB data from RPi Camera then save file to matlab/Python readable format?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, rgb, binaryfiles, picamera

I am taking multiple white light images in a row that I want to split into RGB images later on due to time constraints for my application. I currently save the raw RGB image as a `.data` but cannot figure out how to read the file back into an array to allow me to manipulate it in a separate script. Is there a better way to save this RGB data very quickly so that I have access to it later? or even better split it up into R G and B then save those images individually?

Camera Capture:

`self.camera.capture('file_location.data', 'rgb')`

Read back into Python (Seperate Script):

```
path = 'file_location.data'

with open(path, 'rb') as f:
  contents = f.read()
```

I am able to read the binary file but have not found how to convert  `contents` into an array that I can manipulate.

Comment: can you provide an example of your data file?

Comment: How many images do you need to save in a row? What are the height and width of the images in pixels please? The normal way to save an image is in a PNG or JPEG file. What are the time constraints exactly, please?

Comment: @MarkSetchell I have to take 7 images in a row. I take an image then move a motor, take image move motor etc. I need this process to be as fast as possible. I believe I have it at 20 seconds for all 7 images as of now (outputting ```.data``` files). At each motor position I take a white light image and another background image (no light) and want to save these image as RGB output in order to later extract the R G and B components into 3 separate images. I cannot use PNG or JPEG in this situation. I need to either save the RGB data by itself or separate the images very quickly during imaging.

Comment: @MarkSetchell The height and width is the max resolution of the camera (2592x1944). I have thought of saving these images to an array then saving all 7 images after the process is done but haven't tried yet. Unsure of whether a raspberry Pi  3B+ has enough RAM to handle that large of an Array. 7*(2592x1944x3)

Comment: Those images are only 15MB each, so 7 will take around 105MB which should be pretty easy for a RasPi. You don't need it as a single contiguous array, you could have a list of 7 images.

Comment: You can do a quick test with `im = np.zeros((7,2592,1944,3), dtype=np.uint8)` to see if it works and `print(im.size)` to see the size.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Great thank your for the insight I will try this out.

Comment: Can you explain why you cannot use PNG or JPEG please?

Comment: I do not want the images to be compressed so as of now I am saving as a tiff file. Ideally I want to save the raw image data into a data file to allow for post processing of the image, but cannot figure out how to save this information into a readable file format.

Comment: It actually seems that tiff is probably the easier route for me to take in terms of its ease of use in Matlab and Python. I am by far an amateur with these topics. Do you know of any helpful online resources that would provide information of different types of image files and compression/processing?

Comment: Wikipedia is a very good source, try Googling `wiki tiff` or `wiki JPEG`. How much RAM does your RasPi have? Try `head -1 /proc/meminfo` Is your RasPi on wired Ethernet? Or wifi? Which model RasPi is it?

Comment: We are using a RPi 3B+ that has 895516 kB RAM. It will likely be connected to Wifi but may not be in some situations depending on the situation so I would just assume no Wifi connection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way of doing what you ask - it saves the 7 images in a list in memory so that you can take the photos in rapid sequence and then flush them to disk at a more leisurely pace after your experiment is complete.

You seem to be under the misapprehension that compression means data loss. In the case of [PNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics), the compression is loss-less, unlike JPEG which is lossy.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

# Make 7 random RGB images 2592x1944 and append to list in memory
imageList = []
for i in range(7):
   print(f'Creating image {i}')
   im = np.random.randint(0,256,(1944,2592,3), dtype=np.uint8)
   imageList.append(im)

# Show user length of list
print(f'Number of images in list: {len(imageList)}')

# Save images after experiment is complete
for i,image in enumerate(imageList):
    filename = f'image-{i}.png'
    print(f'Saving image: {filename}')
    Image.fromarray(image).save(filename)
```

**Sample Output**

```
Creating image 0
Creating image 1
Creating image 2
Creating image 3
Creating image 4
Creating image 5
Creating image 6
Number of images in list: 7
Saving image: image-0.png
Saving image: image-1.png
Saving image: image-2.png
Saving image: image-3.png
Saving image: image-4.png
Saving image: image-5.png
Saving image: image-6.png
```

If you run the program, you will see that the 7 images are created almost instantaneously, and only the saving to disk at the end takes a while.

Here are the created files:

```
-rw-r--r--@ 1 mark  staff  15132795  6 Aug 11:01 image-0.png
-rw-r--r--  1 mark  staff  15132768  6 Aug 11:01 image-1.png
-rw-r--r--  1 mark  staff  15132789  6 Aug 11:01 image-2.png
-rw-r--r--  1 mark  staff  15132792  6 Aug 11:01 image-3.png
-rw-r--r--  1 mark  staff  15132790  6 Aug 11:01 image-4.png
-rw-r--r--  1 mark  staff  15132791  6 Aug 11:01 image-5.png
-rw-r--r--  1 mark  staff  15132784  6 Aug 11:01 image-6.png
```

If you want to analyse the memory usage, you can either run `htop` while the program is running and watch the RAM usage there, or you can run it like this:

```
/usr/bin/time -l ./script.py 

        6.79 real         6.98 user         0.21 sys
       162914304  maximum resident set size
               0  average shared memory size
               0  average unshared data size
               0  average unshared stack size
           40470  page reclaims
               0  page faults
               0  swaps
               0  block input operations
               0  block output operations
               0  messages sent
               0  messages received
               0  signals received
               9  voluntary context switches
            2620  involuntary context switches
     48621173737  instructions retired
     30872454100  cycles elapsed
       145956864  peak memory footprint
```

---

Note that you could equally use **OpenCV** instead of **PIL**, just use:

```
import cv2
```

and, at the end

```
cv2.imwrite(filename, image)
```

---

Note that a Raspberry Pi has 4 CPU cores and Python tends to only use one, so if you wanted to be able to store more images, you could start say 3 additional processes that wait for images from the acquisition process and write them to disk. Then you would clear the RAM out of unsaved images at 3 times the rate. This is pretty simple with **Redis** or Python 3.8 multiprocessing shared memory. If you ran a **Redis** instance on your Raspberry Pi, it could run without WiFi (as it would be local), but you could pull the images afterwards (or real-time) from your PC for Matlab to process.